# How to evaluate transition rates of a Markov Jump Process

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains

I am trying to revise for my exam, the following question is 'unseen' material from the course hence we haven't directly studied it and as a result i'm struggling to make a good start on the question.

https://i.gyazo.com/0eb37facbb88a95f22c460e4ce6b9f27
And here's the context we are given:

Bob is twice as likely to be admitted to Hospital A than to Hospital B.

The average waiting time from the time of Bob’s accident until the time of his surgery is 1 month.

The average waiting time from admission to Hospital A until full recovery is 4 months.

The average waiting time from admission to Hospital B until full recovery is 5 months. Based on this information determine the values of the parameters α, β, μ and ν.

So to determine the values of the parameters would I have to set up a system of equations? Would it be in terms of the transition rates eg, 2α = β2α=β? or is the problem more complex than that

Comment: @DavidDiaz Thank you! I tried putting it in as an image but I don't have enough reputation, it should work now! :)

Comment: Oops i'm not sure why it's formatted my working so bad, I did originally have that in my question, based on this information then do I need to set up integrals and such using the average time from hospital A until recovery and the same with hospital B? and then somehow α=2β can be used?

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

- The average waiting time from the time of Bob’s accident until the time of his surgery is just the average length of time he spends in state $1$.  The length of time he spends in state $1$ has cumulative distribution function $\ 1-e^{-(\alpha+\beta)t}\ $ (for $\ t\ge0\ $)—that is, probability density function $\ (\alpha+\beta)e^{-(\alpha+\beta)t}\ $.
- The probability that Bob gets admitted to hospital A is  $\ \frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}\ $, and the probability that he gets admitted to hospital B is $\ \frac{\beta}{\alpha+\beta}\ $, so you're correct that if the former is twice the latter, then $\ \alpha=2\beta\ $.
- The average waiting time from admission to Hospital A until full recovery is just the average length of time Bob will spend in state $2$, given that he enters that state.  The length of time he will spend in that state after entering it has cumulative distribution function $\ 1-e^{-\mu t}\ $ (for $\ t\ge0\ $)—that is, probability density function $\ \mu e^{-\mu t}\ $.
- Similarly, the waiting time from admission to Hospital B until full recovery has cumulative distribution function $\ 1-e^{-\nu t}\ $ (for $\ t\ge0\ $)—that is, probability density function $\ \nu e^{-\nu t}\ $.